# Update state after other state changed

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a react class which loads a list by an api.

pages/cars.js

```
class Cars extends Component{

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const {getCars} = props.actions
    getCars(props.params.page, props.reducerCars.filter)

    this.handlePagination = this.handlePagination.bind(this);
  }

  render() {
    // Render list
  }

}

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  const {reducerCars} = state;
  return {
    reducerCars
  }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
  return{
    actions: bindActionCreators(Actions, dispatch)
  }
}

export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Cars);
```

There is a switch on the page to filter the list.

```
<FormControlLabel
  control={
    <Switch value="5" onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this,5)} color="primary" />
  }
  labelPlacement="start"
  label="Renovate"
/>
```

When this switch is activated, the status in the store will be updated.

```
handleChange(name, event) {
  const newFilter = this.props.reducerCars.filter;

  if(event.target.checked === true) {
    newFilter.push(name);
  } else {
    var index = newFilter.indexOf(name);
    newFilter.splice(index, 1);
  }

  this.props.actions.filter(newFilter);

}
```

actions/actions.js

```
export function filter(filter) {
  return{
    type: CAR_FILTER,
    filter: filter
  }
}
```

reducers/reducers.js

```
if (action.type === CAR_FILTER) {
  return Object.assign({}, state, {
    filter: action.filter
  });
}
```

Only after the switch the api should be refreshed. What's the best way to do this?

I tried to check if the store is updated in the componentWillReceiveProps() but the nextprops is the same as the current props:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
  console.log(this.props.reducerCars.filter);
  console.log(nextProps.reducerCars.filter);

  if(this.props.reducerCars.filter !=== nextProps.reducerCars.filter) {

  }
}
```

I can do a dispatch in the filter action after the switch is updated. But than i also need the currentPage to pass to getCars(currentPage, filter); Or to use the Redux Subscribe option?

What's the best React / Redux solution here?

The full code can be found here: https://github.com/emkedouwe/aircoolednetwork

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways you can do this. One is using

```
    componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
//this will give you your latest state from store
     console.log(nextProps);
    }
```

this nextProps will get you your current state, if you have that state in your 'mapStateToProps'.

Second approach is that you can watch it inside saga middleware for a change, and then update state, and you can update your state in store.

Comment: But because the value is saved in the store nextState is always empty. If i do:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(nextProps);
    console.log(nextState);
}
```
this.props is the same as nextprops and nextstate is empty.

Comment: If you have mapStateToProps and inside you have that state which you are updating in store. Once its updated you get your nextProps, and it has your latest store value. Hope it helps

Comment: you dont have to return reducerCars inside your mapStateToProps

Comment: mapStateToProps is returning the state i'm updating. But after the update this.props is already the same as nextProps.
Reducer can be found here: https://github.com/emkedouwe/aircoolednetwork/blob/master/src/reducers/reducers.js

Comment: I am working your code, and will tell you whats missing

Comment: why is your api not working ... GET http://dev.nl/aircoolednetwork/wp-json/wp/v2/car?per_page=%206&page=1&_embed 404 (Not Found)

Comment: It's a localhost url. You can change it to: https://www.aircoolednetwork.com/wp-json/wp/v2/car?_embed

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import FormGroup from '@material-ui/core/FormGroup';
import FormControlLabel from '@material-ui/core/FormControlLabel';
import Switch from '@material-ui/core/Switch';
import * as Actions from '../actions/actions';
import { CSSTransition, TransitionGroup } from 'react-transition-group';
import CarTeaser from './../components/carteaser.js';
import Pagination from './../components/pagination.js';

class Cars extends Component {

    constructor( props ) {
        super( props );

        const { getCars } = props.actions
        getCars( props.params.page, props.reducerCars.filter )

        this.handlePagination = this.handlePagination.bind( this );
    }

    componentWillReceiveProps( nextProps ) {
        if( this.props.params.page !== nextProps.params.page ) {
            const { getCars } = nextProps.actions
            getCars( nextProps.params.page, this.props.reducerCars.filter )
        }

        console.log( this.props.reducerCars.filter );
        console.log( nextProps.reducerCars.filter );
    }

    filterTest = (testProp) => {
        if(testProp.reducerCars.filter.length !== 0){
            testProp.actions.filter(testProp.reducerCars.filter);
        }
    }

    handleChange( name, event ) {
        const newFilter = this.props.reducerCars.filter;

        if( event.target.checked === true ) {
            newFilter.push( name );
        } else {
            var index = newFilter.indexOf( name );
            newFilter.splice( index, 1 );
        }

        this.props.actions.filter( newFilter );
        this.filterTest(this.props);
    }

    handlePagination( pageNumber ) {
        this.props.router.push( '/cars/' + pageNumber );
    }

    render() {

        const { reducerCars } = this.props;
        const { currentPage, noOfPages, isLoading } = reducerCars;

        if( isLoading ) {
            return (
                <div>Loading...</div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <div className="Cars">
                    <div className="container py-3">
                        <FormGroup aria-label="position" name="position" row>
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                    <Switch value="3" onChange={this.handleChange.bind( this, 3 )} color="primary"/>
                                }
                                labelPlacement="start"
                                label="Original"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                    <Switch value="4" onChange={this.handleChange.bind( this, 4 )} color="primary"/>
                                }
                                labelPlacement="start"
                                label="Custom"
                            />
                            <FormControlLabel
                                control={
                                    <Switch value="5" onChange={this.handleChange.bind( this, 5 )} color="primary"/>
                                }
                                labelPlacement="start"
                                label="Renovate"
                            />
                        </FormGroup>
                    </div>
                    <div className="container my-3">
                        <TransitionGroup className="row">
                            {reducerCars.cars.map( ( car ) => {
                                return (
                                    <CSSTransition
                                        key={car.id}
                                        timeout={0}
                                        classNames="item"
                                    >
                                        <CarTeaser key={car.id} car={car}/>
                                    </CSSTransition>
                                )
                            } )}
                        </TransitionGroup>
                        <div className="container">
                            <Pagination
                                total={parseInt( noOfPages )}
                                current={parseInt( currentPage )}
                                prevText="Prev"
                                showPages={true}
                                nextText="Next"
                                onClickPage={this.handlePagination}
                                baseClassName="pagination justify-content-center"
                            />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            );
        }
    }

}

function mapStateToProps( state ) {
    const { reducerCars } = state;
    return {
        reducerCars
    }
}

function mapDispatchToProps( dispatch ) {
    return {
        actions: bindActionCreators( Actions, dispatch )
    }
}

export default connect(
    mapStateToProps,
    mapDispatchToProps
)( Cars );
```

Comment: Can you explain your solution? You're calling the filter twice like this? 
this.props.actions.filter( newFilter ); and after that: if(testProp.reducerCars.filter.length !== 0){
            testProp.actions.filter(testProp.reducerCars.filter);}

Answer (score 0):

Isn't better to change the filter action like this:

```
export function filter(filter) {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    dispatch({ type: CAR_FILTER, filter: filter });

    const state = getState();

    dispatch(getCars(state.reducerCars.currentPage, filter));
  };
}
```